# Qt - Get audio amplitude from QBytearray

Tags: qt, audio-recording, waveform, amplitude, qbytearray

I'm trying to create a program, using Qt (c++), which can record audio from my microphone using QAudioinput and QIODevice. I made a research and I came up with an example located on the this [page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421287/Cross-Platform-Microphone-Audio-Processing-Utility). This example does what I need.

Now, I am trying to create an audio waveform of the recorded sound. I want to extract audio amplitudes and save them on a QList. To do that I use the following code:

```
//Check the number of samples in input buffer
qint64 len = m_audioInput->bytesReady();

//Limit sample size
if(len > 4096)
    len = 4096;
//Read sound samples from input device to buffer
qint64 l = m_input->read(m_buffer.data(), len);
if(l > 0)
{

    //Assign sound samples to short array
    short* resultingData = (short*)m_buffer.data();

     for ( i=0; i < len; i++ )
     {
         btlist.append( resultingData[ i ]);
     }

}
```

m_audioInput is QAudioinput | m_buffer is QBytearray | m_input is QIODevice | btlist is QList

I use the following QAudioFormat:

```
m_format.setFrequency(44100); //set frequency to 44100
m_format.setSampleRate(44100); //set sample rate to 44100
m_format.setChannels(1); //set channels to mono
m_format.setSampleSize(16); //set sample sze to 16 bit
m_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt ); //signed integer sample
m_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian); //Byte order
m_format.setCodec("audio/pcm"); //set codec as simple audio/pcm
```

When I print my QList, using qWarning() << btlist.at(int), I get some positive and negative numbers which represents my audio amplitudes. I used Microsoft Excel to plot the data and compare it with the actual sound waveform.

(EDIT BASED ON THE OP COMMENT)
I am drawing the waveform using QPainter in Qt like this

```
  for(int i = 1; i < btlist.size(); i++){ 
       double x1 = (i-(i/1.25))-0.2;
       double y1 = btlist.at(i-1);
       double x2 = i-(i/1.25);
       double y2 = btlist.at(i);
       painter.drawLine(x1,y1,x2, y2); 
  }
```

**The problem** is that I also get lots of zeros (0) in my QList between the amplitude data like [this](http://pastebin.com/aYRUPiE5), which if I draw as a waveform they are a straight line, which is not normal because it causes corruption to my waveform.
My question is why is that happening? What these zeros (0) represent? Am I doing something wrong? Also, is there a better way to extract audio amplitudes from QBytearray?

Thank you.

Comment: how do you draw your waveform??

Comment: Hello UmNyobe, am drawing the waveform using QPainter in Qt like this:                                                                 for(int i = 1; i < btlist.size(); i++){

    painter.drawLine(((i-(i/1.25))-0.2),btlist.at(i-1),(i-(i/1.25)),btlist.at(i));

}

Comment: can you show your waveform too, and what do you mean by corruption??

Comment: You use len when filling the data, but the actually read bytes is l, not len. So if l < len, you're filling the list with invalid data from the buffer.

Comment: Here is what I get [link](http://s7.postimage.org/fxmo85pnf/waveform.png) when I record to this sound [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TGCFGsQIx0). By corruption I mean amplitude with zero value.

Comment: Hello Frank Osterfeld, I changed "len" with "l" as you suggested but I still get the same thing.

Comment: @DaReDeViL see the end of my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawline method you are using take ***integer values***. Which means most of the time both of your `x` indexes will be the same. By simplifiyng your formula the `x` value at a given `i` is `(i/5.0)`. By itself it is not an issue because the lines will be superposed, and it is a perfect way of drawing (just to make sure that's what you want to do).

The zero you see can be perfectly valid. They represent ***silence***.

The real issue is that the range of your 16 bits PCM values is `[-32767 , 32768]`. I doubt that the paint device you are using cover this range. You need to normalize your y-axis. Moreover, it seems taht [the qt coordinated system doesn't have negative values](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/coordsys.html) (edit: Nevermind the negatives, its says logical coordinates are converted).

For instance, convert your pcm values using :

```
  ((btlist.at(i) / MAX_AMPLITUDE + 1.0) / 2) * paintDevice.height();
```

***Edit:***

Btw, you are not using `l`, which is the real amount  of data you read. If it is inferior to `len`, you will read invalid values at the end of your buffer, possibly read garbage\ read zeros\crash.

And your buffer is a ***byte buffer***. And you iterate using a ***short pointer***. So whether you use `l` or `len` the **maximum size need to be divided by two**. This is probably the cause of the ling line of zero in your picture.

```
 for ( i=0; i < l/2; i++ )
 {
     btlist.append( resultingData[ i ]);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did notice that mistake you and Frank Osterfeld mentioned. Thank you. I changed it to "l" but I still get the same issue. The plot is the same as [link](http://s7.postimage.org/fxmo85pnf/waveform.png). I also tried to plot the data using Excel and I get the same thing.

Comment: I did now. Oh my god! I did not noticed that mistake. Thank you very much sir. I appreciate yours and Frank Osterfeld help. Thank you! :)

Comment: typical mistakes. I make tons of them :)